# Dynamic Action refresh all reports in a page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

1. I have a page with to many reports
2. When I change an Item I want to refresh all the reports on the page
3. I have one dynamic action (on item change) that as a lot of refresh (true) actions to refresh all the reports.

I  want to know if theres a way/comand/DynamicAction/Code that refreshes all the reports in the page with a single DynamicAction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single JavaScript action the executes the following

```
$('.refreshme').trigger('apexrefresh');
```

And apply the `refreshme` class to all the regions you'd like to refresh

[image: Region CSS Class]

Answer (score 1):

How about removing dynamic action and **submitting** the page once the item is changed? Submit will *force* all reports to refresh.

Comment: And if the problem here is that submitting does some other things as well(saves something into DB or something, just set a condition for those things to not trigger on submit unless the save button was pressed or something)

Comment: it's a visual requirement because the page as some graphs and the client likes the refresh animations and doesnt want any submit,