# Oracle Apex - refresh all subregions with one refresh in dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working with APEX 19.2.0.00.18. I have a page with a static region with 4 chart subregions, plus a radio button that allows the user to select which series (total, mean, median) to display in the charts. I have a dynamic action set up to refresh charts when the radio button value is changed. This dynamic action consists of:

1. execute null PL/SQL code to submit the radio button value
2. refresh chart subregion 1
3. refresh chart subregion 2
4. refresh chart subregion 3
5. refresh chart subregion 4

Is there any way to simplify this to refresh all 4 chart subregions with a single refresh? I have multiple static regions like this (i.e., containing multiple chart subregions) on this page, so reloading the entire page is not an ideal option.

Answer (score 5):

Scott's answer is pretty much correct, but if you decide to use the newer apex.region JS API, you have to use it with a region static id.
So just give the regions you want to refresh a static id and then use the API like this (e.g. in a Execute JavaScript Dynamic Action):

```
apex.region('MY_STATIC_ID1').refresh();
apex.region('MY_STATIC_ID2').refresh();
apex.region('MY_STATIC_ID3').refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this simplified things a lot. I'm wondering if there is a solution that doesn't involve explicitly assigning static IDs to all the subregions and running a separate .refresh() for each subregion. E.g., if the parent region has an ID of 'parentregion' is there a way to run a single .refresh() targeting all subregions of the parentregion?

Comment: Ahh, I did wonder if it expected static ID, or the demonstration was just illustrating it as a selector.

Comment: Hmm you could give every region a specific class and then loop through all divs which has that class assigned to: `$('div.my-region-class').each(function() {
  apex.region($(this).attr('id')).refresh();
});`

Answer (score 4):

Answer previously here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126513/527513

Can be applied a number of ways, but you're using the JS API refresh any region with a given selector, in this case the refreshme class

```
$('.refreshme').trigger('apexrefresh');
```

The  API offering has changed over time,  [apex.region](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/region.html#refresh) being the newer method.

```
apex.region( "static_id1" );
apex.region( "static_id2" );
```

As Daniel noted, these need to be supplied as static IDs, not a given selector. I should have realised this since the example was absent the # of the static ID.

Comment: how to do this from PLSQL side ?

Comment: Without further context, this doesn't make too much sense. I would suggest raising your own question.

Comment: I was able to do this with the below function.

APEX_IR.CLEAR_REPORT (
    p_page_id   IN NUMBER,
    p_region_id IN NUMBER,
    p_report_id IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL );