# Oracle Apex 22.21 - How to refresh multiple regions with one dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two charts on one page. There are also two **datepicker items** (Date From and Date To) so the user can choose between two dates and get a range of values.

[image]

I understand how to implement the datepicker for one chart and it works for me as expected. But how can I have the datepicker refresh the both charts at the same time?

I've found [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356959/oracle-apex-refresh-all-subregions-with-one-refresh-in-dynamic-action) and followed Daniel's answer to give each region a static id.

So I've added the static id of `region1` to the first chart and `region2` to the second chart.

[image]

Then, I changed the datepicker dynamic action *selection type* to *Javascript Expression* and added the following

```
apex.region('#region1').refresh();
apex.region('#region2').refresh();
```

[image]

But the refresh doesn't fire when I choose a new date.

Daniel's answer in the other question did mention a JS API. Is this something I link up with Apex or is it already included out the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to refresh multiple regions with one dynamic action

I presume/hope that this should do:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Apex does make actions like these very easy to implement. I do wish their documentation was a bit more extensive..