# Charts with FILTER in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I watched a lot of tutorials and I know how to create different diagrams and charts. The problem is, my boss needs dynamic charts. That means he wants to have two tables (like kalender) so that he selects the year and the month (Filter by month and year). After that, charts will be created from the table. 
(For example total sales in January 2018 for various products)

I searched on the internet, but did not find a proper tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an item, say P1_YEAR.

Create a dynamic action on 'change' on this item that refreshes the chart region.

In the chart region, set 'page items to submit' as P1_YEAR, and add the filter to your chart, eg:

```
where year = :P1_YEAR
```

Repeat for other items such as month.  They could use the same dynamic action, just list multiple items.

If you have a large number of charts, as an alternative to dozens of actions, you can add class to each region you want to refresh, and run a JavaScript action to refresh all regions with that class

```
$('.refreshme').trigger('apexrefresh');
```

[Dynamic Action refresh all reports in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116046/dynamic-action-refresh-all-reports-in-a-page/58126513#58126513)

A default for P1_YEAR could come in the form of a 'before regions' computation, or an NVL in your filter

```
where  t.year = nvl(:P1_year, t.year)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we have 10 charts on a page and after choose of start and end date, all charts should change.

Comment: and do you know how can I set a default value for :P_YEAR

Comment: I extended my answer.